AWS DMS Test Endpoint fails: Login timeout expired
Appreciate any help with this:
I have a DMS replication instance set up where I have set up source and target end points. The source is a SQL Server database.
Currently I am trying to test the connection and I get:

Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failed to connect Network error has occurred, Application-Detailed-Message: RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: HYT00 NativeError: 0 Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]

Would appreciate any help with this.
The source database is hosted on a VM which is connected to via a VPN connection. To test, I also setup an EC2 instance which is in the same VPC, same security group and same subnets as the replication instance, the EC2 instance is able to connect via a script while the DMS instance is not.
